# Find m most distant points from a set of n points

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

I would like to find the $m$ (where $n$ $\geq$ $m$ > 1) maximally distant subset of points from a collection of $n$ $d$-dimensional points.  Maximally distant means the sum of the pairwise distances between the $m$ point subset is maximized.

This $m$ point subset will maximize some sort of distance metric (I am primarily interested in $L_2$-norm).  The dimension $d$ will likely be 3 - however if there was a way to define a distance metric that was meaningful in $SE(3)$ (Special-Euclidean Group Lie Algebra) that would be favorable (the points in my motivating example are 6-Degrees of Freedom locations in 3-$D$ space i.e. 3 - position + 3 - orientation).  Having said this any solution that works just in cartesian 3-space will also be fine.

Here is a simple example in 2-$D$

A set of 16 2-$D$ points
$$\begin{array}{rrrr}
+ & + & + & + \\
+ & + & + & + \\
+ & + & + & + \\
+ & + & + & + \\
\end{array}$$

Would lead to the maximally distant subset of $m$ = 4 points
$$\begin{array}{rrrr}
+ &   &   & + \\
  &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   \\
+ &   &   & + \\
\end{array}$$

Or for example with $m$ = 2 one of the two possible solutions would be
$$\begin{array}{rrrr}
+ &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   \\
  &   &   &   \\
  &   &   & + \\
\end{array}$$

Note: I found a similar question on this topic, but unfortunately the proposed answer requires convex optimization (QP) which is not suitable for the very large number of points that I require ($n$).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400905/most-mutually-distant-k-elements-clustering

I have tried the following algorithm

```
Add the n d-dimensional points to a kd-tree
while subset S size is greater than n
   find the point q from the kd-tree that is least distant to any of its neighbors
   remove point q from the kd-tree and the subset S
return the subset S of m maximally distant points
```

This is obviously non-deterministic since the order in which the points are removed affects the eventual subset of $S$ (this however occasionally returns the correct solution). But the complexity is $(n - m)log(n)$ which is favorable considering $n$ will be $> 100,000$.

Does anyone have ideas about how to improve/replace the above algorithms whilst keeping the complexity down?  Even if there is away to solve the QP in reasonable time with very large $n$ that would be great.

Comment: What is "maximally distant"? What exactly is to be maximized?

Comment: It's not even clear to me what this means in the case $m=1$. Would you want the point whose closest point is farthest away? the point whose farthest point is farthest away? the point farthest away from the average of the other points?

Comment: Why did you classify it as graph theory when your question doesn't mention a graph?

Comment: How large is $d$? This can affect the best choice.

Comment: No doubt the *graph-theory* mis-tagging results from the OP's idea of using a $kd$-tree. It should be tagged *metric-geometry* and *discrete-geometry*. I have so edited.

Comment: @GerryMyerson to clarify your question - you are right m > 1

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke thanks for amending the tag - I am new on this forum and was influenced by existing implementation which is using the kd-tree

Comment: I have amended the question to reflect you comments - thanks!

Comment: This question uses a lot of terms which are unfamiliar to me and which I think might also be unfamiliar to other people in this forum who might still be interested in this question (as I am).  What is SE(3)?  What is a kd-tree?  What is 6-DOF?  You also still haven't said what you want to maximize: is it the minimum over all pairs of the pairwise distances among your points, or some other function of the distances?

Comment: Hi @HughThomas, thanks for replying. Here is a link to the kd-tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)

Comment: I think perhaps you should just compute the convex hull of your $n$ points, and then select $m$ of the hull points. I suggest this without really understanding what you are seeking. :-)

Comment: Thanks @JosephO'Rourke I thought this too, but consider a set of $n$ > $3$ points on a line where you are seeking the $n$ > $m$ >= $3$ subset that are maximally distant.

Comment: @difftator I believe that your problem is NP-hard, but it can be formulated as a binary linear programming problem; unfortunately the question has been put on hold, which is a pitty because I see several interesting aspects to it. Maybe you should only state the problem and ask for solutions or heuristics and, do not mention what you have tried so far.

Comment: I vote to put the question off hold as (at least to me) it is clear that an efficient heuristic for finding a maximum-weight m-clique in a complete graph, whose edge-weights resemble (euclidean) distances, is sought. As the problem can be interpreted differently (e.g. Computational Geometry, or Graph Theory), it would be interesting to see the exact algorithms or heuristics found on ground of those interpretations.

Comment: An alternative to the strategy the OP proposes would be to find the minimal distance between a pair of points in the set, and discard one of those points, and repeat until only m points remain.  The time would be quadratic, but I guess the outcome would be better than with the algorithm the OP proposes.

Comment: @ManfredWeis I have just found a better reference for solving Binary Quadratic Programming problems
"Solving Large Scale Binary Quadratic Problems:Spectral Methods vs. Semidefinite Programming"
It seems that O(n^3) solutions exist (Eigenvalues) that fits nicely with large n and can be easily implemented with a standard linear algebra package. So I think I will pursue that solution.

Comment: @difftator you don't need quadratic binary programming; linear binary programming is sufficient. If you need assistance in the formulation, let me know. Also a relaxed, i.e. ordinary linear programming formulation is possible of which the solution may be a good approximation of the exact solution.

Comment: @ManfredWeis any suggestions would be welcome.  Thanks!

Comment: @difftator here the promised binary programming formulation: introduce binary variables $v_i$ for the selecting a point itself and $e_{ij}$ for selecting the pair $v_i$ and $v_j$ of points and, let further $w_{ij}$ denote the entries of the distance table. The objective is then to maximize the sum over all $w_{ij}e_{ij}$ under the constraints, that $e_{ij}\le v_i, e_{ij}\le v_j,\Sigma v_i = m, \Sigma e_{ij} = m^2$. In the relaxed version the additional constraint $e_{ij}\ge v_i+v_j-1$ further reduces the integrality gap. I hope that helps in utilizing existing LP solvers for your problem.

Comment: Came here for a solution to this exact problem and it is annoying that it is closed because a couple of people couldn't understand the question, which I think is quite clear.